# Products are too close in wooCommerce with 2013 WordPress theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, woocommerce

I have installed wooCommerce plugin in WordPress, then activated the "Twenty Thirteen" theme and have added 4 products.

Does anybody please know how to fix the problem, that the products are show too close and their "Add to basket" labels overlap (at least in Russian language, here [fullscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRfp2.png))?

[image: website screenshot]

I have tried different widget configurations, like removing the basket from the right side - this doesn't help.

If needed, I'm comfortable with editing JS, CSS and PHP files - but don't know WordPress well.

Comment: have you tried changing the layout to 3 columns instead of 4?

Comment: I would like to change the layout to 3 columns, but can't find where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways that you could fix this layout issue, but here's a quick fix for you.

Add this to your css:

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product, .woocommerce-page ul.products li.product {
    min-width: 220px;
}
```

This isn't a perfect solution, and a look at your actual image sizes and desired output would help to make this work better, but this will fix your issue.

Another possible solution is to use the shortcode in the template file for your shop and limit the output to 3 columns.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[products ids="1, 2, 3, 4, 5" columns="3"]');?>
```

As mentioned in another answer, to directly change the number of columns without creating a custom template for the shop page:

```
add_filter( 'loop_shop_columns', function() { return 3; } );
```

Add this to your functions.php file within your theme.

Comment: +1 thanks - your CSS workaround works. Regarding your 2nd suggestion - what template file do you mean please? I've searched my Wordpress files for all `do_shortcode` strings, but non of them has `products` as argument.

Comment: This would require you to create a custom page template for your shop page. It's pretty involved and requires a bit of knowledge about the way wordpress handles templates and pages. I'd recommend using the add_filter mentioned at the end of my answer.

Comment: Thank you, I've tried your suggestion to add `add_filter( 'loop_shop_columns', function(){return 3;});` to `functions.php` and it changes the column number, but the products are still too close and overlap. Your CSS workaround has worked well for me.

Answer (score 2):

To change the number of products per row use `loop_shop_columns` filter.

```
/* functions.php */

add_filter( 'loop_shop_columns', function() { return 3; } );
```

But that still will not solve the problem, you will probably have to [override](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/css-structure/) WooCommerce styles for button and product list elements ( note that first and last elements in the row have specific CSS classes 'first' and 'last' ).

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did to move the products apart.
Add this to your css:

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product, .woocommerce-page ul.products li.product {
padding: 15px;
```

}