# Products in WooCommerce too close to each other

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using WooCommerce with a Virtue theme. For the last few months I have used Polylang translation, and only recently updated to WPLM. I do not know it's what caused it but the products suddenly became too close to each other and they are even overlaping the page numbers on the bottoms of the page. I looked at [Products are too close in wooCommerce with 2013 WordPress theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23569601/products-are-too-close-in-woocommerce-with-2013-wordpress-theme) but this didn't help me.

Does anybody know how to fix the problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OO4Df.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can Change number or products per row to 3. use this code

```
add_filter('loop_shop_columns', 'loop_columns'); if (!function_exists('loop_columns')) {
function loop_columns() {
    return 3; // 3 products per row
} }
```

I think it will work for you

Answer (score 0):

It's hard finding what causes your problem without looking at your codes. But WooCommerce products are usually listed using the "li.product" class. Adding the following code to your stylesheet can help you adjust the margins of your products.

```
li.product {
    margin-right: 2em;
}
```

If that doesn't work try this:

```
li.product {
    margin-right: 2em!iimportant;
}
```

Let me know if this helps.